# Push Notification in ?Iphone

Tags: iphone

I m trying to implement Push Notifications in Iphone SDK 4.0.I have done up to the point of generating Token for device.I don't know how to proceed further.I need example to test Push Notification.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No easy answer for this, but you might want to start with the programming guide (link below).  Be aware that you'll also need a server to generate the push notifications - you could enlist a 3rd party service for this - like Urban Airship

http://urbanairship.com/products/push/

Notification Programming Guide from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Good luck.  Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If you want an open source alternative you have one in PHP:

PHP Apple Push Notification Provider

http://code.google.com/p/php-apns/